# Ocaml acquiring list of mutex locks

Tags: oop, dictionary, locking, ocaml, mutex

So what I'm doing is trying to produce a function called transact. When given a  list of locks [x1;x2;...;xn],  a function (f:'a->'b), and a argument (v:'a),  running (f v) accesses any data protected by locks [x1;x2;...;xn], it should acquire the locks, run the function on the argument, and release the locks without causing deadlock.

I know how to get a single mutex lock as for a sample simple function below, but I'm not sure how to go through a list of them.

```
method deposit(int amt):unit = 
    Mutex.lock mylock ; 
    if balance + amt < max_balance then
        balance <- balance + amt ; 
    Mutex.unlock mylock
end
```

Would I want to use List.iter function to go through the locks or map to apply the function? I'm using the Core.Std library.

Answer (score 0):

From your example code I’d say you want to use List.iter; there is (apparently) no interesting result of `Mutex.lock`.

The classic way to avoid deadlock is to impose an order on your locks, and always apply `Mutex.lock` according to this order.